# List of buttons that set value to model and submit

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, button

I want to make a list of buttons that will set a value in the selectedTime model.
Below is the code that i got, it shows how i want it to look but could be completely wrong.

```html
<form name="room" ng-submit="vm.postEvent()">
<button ng-click="vm.selectedTime = 15" > 15</button>
<button ng-click="vm.selectedTime = 30" > 30</button>
<button ng-click="vm.selectedTime = 60" > 60</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have a form in order to doing this.
Just 3 buttons are enought

```
<button ng-click="vm.selectedTime = 15" > 15</button>
<button ng-click="vm.selectedTime = 30"> 30</button>
<button ng-click="vm.selectedTime = 60"> 60</button>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works now. But i did need a form because i need to call a method with the button as well. Edited my question with what i have now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.selectedTime" >
<button     type="submit"  ng-click="vm.selectedTime =15" > 15</button>
<button     type="submit" ng-click="vm.selectedTime =30" > 30</button>
<button     type="submit" ng-click="vm.selectedTime =60"> 60</button>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/nsra4s2q/)

Let me know if thr r any changes

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it works now. Edited my question with what i have now.

Answer (score 0):

well instead of doing it with list of buttons , I suggest you should do it with a list ( using select and option with ng-repeat and value as the value at array index of option serial number).....

```
<select ng-model="varname">
    <option ng-repeat="x in array" value="{{x}}">
        {{x}}
    </option>
</select>
```

It should do your work and It will also not be so confusing as of number of buttons occupying more space , in list you know you have to select a value.. Go for it